# Can't print/obtain specific rows of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting, println

let's say I have a multidimensional array which for simplicity's sake we'll say just holds numbers:

```
double[][] MDarray = new double[10][20]
```

So this will be 20 rows by 10 columns. With the way my program works, writing into these elements means that the final 10-15 elements of every row will likely be populated with just '0's, here is an example of what my MD array's would look like with populated elements:

```
[
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, ..]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, ..]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, ..]
.. etc
```

How does one access just a specific row? This MD array is supposed to be a datastructure holding the results to my program. There is a 'winner' from this program, so if the program decides that '7' is the winner, then row 8 of this array holds data fundamental to the completion of my program code.

Attempting to print results like this:

```
int bestResult = 7;
System.out.println("The best result is by " + bestResult +  ": ");
        for(int j = 0; j < RT[bestResult].length; j++) { 
            System.out.print(RT[bestResult][j]+" - "); 
           }
```

Will just print the wrong elements! For example I know the answer in the array should print:

```
11 - 10 - 0 - 0 - 0 ..etc
```

Instead it prints elements from previous rows/prints random non-sense:

```
4 - 0 - 11 - 10 - 0 - 0 - 0 ..etc
```

Attempting to print it like this however:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(MDarray));
```

Is evidence that data is being stored in my arrays correctly, as it **prints results exactly correct** every time.

So my question is: Is there an approach to printing and accessing results with Arrays.deepToString() or something similar? I mostly want to access the row of the winning result, trim off the excess 0's (which I'll figure out after solving this) and send the results to a web application for use. 
Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There is no way to reproduce your problem from what you have given us.

Comment: Do you simply mean to use `MDarray` instead of `RT` in the loop?

Comment: `So this will be 20 rows by 10 columns.` - It is the other way around

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but someone below gave me the answer I was looking for. Also I'll make sure to read into the links provided here once I've finished this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one access just a specific row?

You can access the row of a 2 dimensional array by returning the element of the first dimension with the index of the desired row number.

Code example:

```
double[][] array = {{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};

double[] winner = array[0];
```

`winner` will correspond to the first "row" of your array. The output of:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winner));`

will then give you the result:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Everyone's pointed the error of my ways (which I'll read into once Ive finished this project), but you're the first to provide me with the answer I want, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> `double[][] MDarray = new double[10][20]`
>
> So this will be 20 rows by 10 columns. With the way my program works,
>   writing into these elements means that the final 10-15 elements of
>   every row will likely be populated with just '0's, here is an example
>   of what my MD array's would look like with populated elements:
>
> [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, ..] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, ..]
>   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, ..] .. etc

I think you misunderstood how multidimensional arrays work.
The highlighted line of code that I'm referencing is actually creating 10 rows of 20 columns each. The way to access a concrete row of the multidimensional array is like you've done before:

```
System.out.println(cool_MDarray[myFavoriteRow].length);
```

Or accessing a member of it:

```
System.out.println("Element is: "+md_array[index_row][index_col].toString());
```

Still, if none of these were your problem I'd recommend you to check the way you're filling your MD array.